# Some WinSCP commands in a batch file are not working

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I am trying to download files from an SFTP server to my local machine, with created a date-wise folder using WinSCP. But it's falling at the point of `lcd`.

Here is my script.

````
@echo off

set datetime=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%
set "mydir=D:\Test\%datetime%\"
mkdir "%mydir%"

echo My Directory is created "%mydir%"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
/log="D:\temp\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
/command ^
"open sftp://username:password@sftp.server1/logs/Test/ -hostkey=""ssh-key=""" ^

"lcd %mydir%" ^

"get *.xml>1D" ^
"exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
echo Success
) else (
echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%```
````

Here is the error in the log:

```
> 2021-03-18 09:17:10.392 lcd D:\Test\18032021\
< 2021-03-18 09:17:10.392 Script: Unknown command '
< 2021-03-18 09:17:10.392 lcd'.
. 2021-03-18 09:17:10.393 Script: Failed
. 2021-03-18 09:17:10.393 Script: Exit code: 1
. 2021-03-18 09:17:10.393 Closing connection.
. 2021-03-18 09:17:10.393 Sending special code: 1
. 2021-03-18 09:17:10.579 Session sent command exit status 0
. 2021-03-18 09:17:10.579 Main session channel closed
. 2021-03-18 09:17:10.580 All channels closed
```

I tried with many options but it's still failing. Any suggestion pointer much appreciated.

Regards,
Aniruddha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file in your question cannot produce the error you are describing. It won't even pass the `lcd` to WinSCP, as your batch file syntax is wrong.

When you want to break a command in a batch file to multiple lines, you need to end each broken line with `^` and the next line needs to be indented.

- Your empty lines do not end with `^` (like the one between `open` and `lcd` command)
- None of your continuation lines are indented.

This should work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="D:\temp\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@sftp.server1/logs/Test/ -hostkey=""ssh-key=""" ^
    "lcd %mydir%" ^
    "get *.xml>1D" ^
    "exit"
```

See WinSCP FAQ [Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)